# Point cloud not normalized, how do you normalize with lidR?

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am using terrestrial LiDAR data, I ran the `las_check()` function on a file. I get check marks and everything is good until the normalization in the preprocessing. Is there an R code to do the normalization?

```
 Checking preprocessing already done 
  - Checking ground classification... yes
  - Checking normalization... no
  - Checking negative outliers... ✓
  - Checking flightline classification
```

I am attempting to take terrestrial LiDAR measurements and use package `lidR` to create a DTM and voxelize my data so I can use package `forestr` to give me additional metrics I can't get out of `lidR` package. I have read several papers that seem to create a DTM and voxelize easy. I read the `lidR` book https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/io.html#asprs-compliance  but I am still new and feel like a dummy when it comes to all this.

Answer (score 2):

The check for pre-processing does not tell you if it is "good" or "not good". It indicates if it is done or not. I mean, a non-normalized point cloud is not "bad". It is not normalized and depending on your analysis in may be suitable or not to normalize. You can normalize with `normalize_height()`. There is a chapter about [height normalization](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/norm.html) btw.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I guess, I just don't understand R enough just yet to translate the book and examples in it to my dataset. I am learning so thanks for the feedback.